# Updating page content using JS during asynchronous operation

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I am trying to solve an issue with webservice call in my MVC 4 project. What I am doing is that when user submits form on page, I call webservice and wait for result. Meanwhile server returns callbacks (it is returning strings containing finished steps of work on server side). What I would like to do is to display contents of "log" I am building from callback on the page and refresh it repeatedly to display the progress.

The issue I run into is, that either I will have asynchronous call of webservice in my controller in which case I am not waiting for result from webservice and that means that user will not stay on the page that should be displaying progress, or I will call it synchronously, in which case javascript on the page will not get response from controller until the final response arrives (so no updates are displayed).

My desired flow is:

1. User submits the form
2. Server is called in controller
3. Server sends callbacks, controller processess them by expanding "log" variable with whatever arrives
4. User still sees the same page, where "log" (contained in specific div) is being periodically refreshed by javascript while controller waits for final result from server
5. Server returns final result
6. Controller finishes its code and returns new view

This is my post method, which currently doesnt wait for the response and proceeds immediately further:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SubmitDetails
               (DocuLiveInstallationRequest submittedRequest, string command)
{
    request = submittedRequest;
    try
    {
        switch (command)
        {
            case "Test":
                {
                    request.OnlyTest = true;
                    DocuLiveInstallationStatus installStatus 
                                                       = await IsValidStatus();
                    if (installStatus == null)
                    {
                        ViewBag.Fail = Resources.AppStart.TestNoResult;
                        return View("SubmitDetails", request); ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        status = installStatus;
                        if (status.Result)
                        {
                            ViewBag.Success = Resources.AppStart.TestSucces;
                            ViewBag.Log = installLog;
                        }
                        TempData["installationStatus"] = installStatus;
                        return View("SubmitDetails", request);
                    }
                }
            case "Submit":
                {
                    request.OnlyTest = false;
                    DocuLiveInstallationStatus installStatus = await Install();
                    if (installStatus == null)
                    {
                        ViewBag.Fail = Resources.AppStart.InstallationNoResult;
                        return View("SubmitDetails", request); ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        status = installStatus;
                        TempData["installationStatus"] = installStatus;
                        TempData["installLog"] = installLog;
                        return RedirectToAction("Login",controllerName:"Login");
                    }
                }
        }
        ViewBag.TestFail = Resources.AppStart.SubmitFailure;
        return View("SubmitDetails", request); ;
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

this is javascript I prepared for the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$("#submitDetails").click(function () {
            var progress = 0;
            //$("#submitDetails").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            var statusUpdate = setInterval(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "/AppStart/GetInstallProgress",
                    datatype: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data && data != "") {
                            $("div.status-message").text(progress);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, 2000);
        //});
    });
</script>
```

Currently I just display the log on the next page (at this stage of development server returns response very swiftly), but I need to call the server, display progress from callbacks while waiting for result and THEN navigate to another page (depending on the result). I feel like I am very close, but I can't get it working.

PS: I am open to other solutions than updating page content. I don't really mind how the goal will be accomplished, but updating the page is preferred by the customer.

Comment: If you need more than one response from the server, you need to make more than one call.
Asynchrony here is how each end is handling its work. The client issues the call and returns to not block the UI and is notified when a response arrives. The server returns to the request handling pool and is notified when the work is done to send the response to the client.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am actually solving that need using callbacks from server. So when the call is made, UI is no longer blocked, but server sends back callbacks which are processed by controller. What I need to do is to check regularly (i.e. every 2 seconds) how that processing goes and display it in the view using Javascript. Which cannot be done the way I am trying to do it - until the response from server is returned, I cant access controller from "outside" (by JS) - call is waiting for the server to respond - and when it does, I no longer need JS updates.